# Quartz: run task once a day,without repeatInterval

Tags: java, task, quartz-scheduler, repeat

config:

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

    </bean>

    <!-- Cron Trigger -->
    <bean id="cronTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 45 16 ? * MON-FRI" />

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I need to run task at 16:45 every working day one time.
`simpleTrigger` warns if i don't use `repeatInterval`,due to it can't be `0`    , but i don't need it,because need my task executed once a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you even *have* simpleTrigger? Your cronTrigger ought to be sufficient to run the task at 16:45 every weekday.

```
<!-- Cron Trigger -->
<bean id="cronTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 45 16 ? * MON-FRI" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
        <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
        <ref bean="cronTrigger" /> <!-- use cronTrigger instead of simpleTrigger -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: StriplingWarrior,thank you for point,I was unattentive,but strange,this expression doesn't still work: 0 45 16 ? * MON-FRI,and this expression works ok:0/5 * * * * ?